# MongoDB: C# or JavaScript?

Tags: c#, javascript, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am not deep in working with MongoDB. But i want to use it with C# driver. I guess that not all features can be available in this driver (Am i right?). Or for example, it easy to find some code written on javascript and, so, it seems easy to use it without mapping/finding appropriate methods in C# driver. I know that MongoDB is written on C++, but as i understand that the main/native driver language is javascript. So i am interesting in how can i run javascript from C# for working with MongoDB? and does this help in getting all features from MongoDB? If it does, tell me please, how to embed and run javascript in C#? Of course, i need fast and easy to use realization, you know;)))))

Edit: which driver will be faster: C# or JavaScript?

Comment: Assuming you are using [this](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp) C# driver, [here](http://github.com/samus/mongodb-csharp/blob/master/examples/Simple/Main.cs) is an example of how to use it from C# (no JavaScript required).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most of the functionality should be made available at the C# level by the driver.  If, however, you want to do some more advanced queries, like a map-reduce, you're sort of stuck with writing some Javascript - it's like writing SQL for an RDBMS.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to update this since there's a lot more functionality in the C# driver now and, where there is not, you can try using NoRM ([NoRM on Github](https://github.com/atheken/NoRM)) or reviewing the source code for some inspiration. Note that this is not the official driver so don't expect support from 10gen if you have a support contract (although I have seen members of the 10gen team actively helping out in the NoRM user group).

Comment: I should mention that there are some other great drivers out there other than NoRM (Samus, for example - also available with source code). NoRM and Samus are simply the two with which I am most familiar.